# How to solve Service call using constant.service.ts file in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, service, angular-ui-router

I'm not able to figure out what's the wrong with service call in angular. It works in other service call in same file. Can you please take a look and let me know what I'm missing?

Following code works fine --

client-agreement.service.ts

```
getClientAgreementById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.constantService.getUrl(`${this.constantService.CLIENT_AGREEMENT}/${id}`));
  }
```

constant.service.ts

```
CLIENT_AGREEMENT = 'onboarding/client-agreement';
```

Following code does not work, what could be issue?

client-agreement.service.ts

```
removeClientAgreementFromJobs(id: number) {
    alert(this.constantService.getUrl(`${this.constantService.JOB_CLIENT_AGREEMENT}/${id}`));
    return this.http.delete(this.constantService.getUrl(`${this.constantService.JOB_CLIENT_AGREEMENT}/${id}`));
  }
```

constant.service.ts

```
JOB_CLIENT_AGREEMENT = 'api/JobClientagreements';
```

Comment: Where do you call `removeClientAgreementFromJobs` can you show us a snippet and compare it to `getClientAgreementById`

Comment: Compare and check if your subscribe event part is correct

Comment: Hi Ondie - I've attached screen shot -- it has three shots together. First one shows the inspect onboarding/client-agreement/130 service is getting called perfectly. In Second screen shot shows api/JobClientagreements/130 getting called in alert but in Browser we don't see anything -- showing totally blank in Network tab (in third screen shot). What am I missing ?

Comment: Hi Zam - Yes, I compared it. But didn't find amything. Attached screen shot to compare. Let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wherever you are calling your service please subscribe then only you can see XHR request.

this.clientAggrementService.removeClientAgreementFromJobs(130).subscribe(i=> {
})

wherever you are consuming your service please subscribe then you can see XHR request.

Comment: Thank you, Mitra. I forgot to subscribe. Thanks for pointing out.